# How can I create randomness with Solana?

Tags: solana

I'm curious if there are currently any ways to create randomness in Solana programs?

I'm aware that Solana uses a proof of stake mechanism which implies to me that the blockhashes are not reliable since proof of stake mechanisms can easily create new blockhashes.

I'm also familiar with Chainlink's VRF on Ethereum, however it doesn't seem like this can be implemented on Solana, again due to proof of stake?

Answer (score 4):

Shouldn't be a problem implementing something like chainlink's VRF oracle on Solana. It's based on pre-commitment and reveal.

Your question is a little vague, though.

Assume you you just want a random source, but you haven't elaborated on the type of randomness or the use-case.

Comment: Thanks for the response, yeah basically a random number that I can use for a heads or tails game with payouts. In my research Chainlink's VRF doesn't work well with proof of stake since VRF uses blockhash as a seed and POS blockchains can easily modify the blockhash. Which means the validator node operator can easily collude with the chainlink node operator to game the system?

Comment: how about generating a new key pair?

Comment: Also chainlink VRF is not out yet isn't it? Any ETA on when it would be available on Solana?

Answer (score 4):

You can try ORAO's VRF, it only takes a few transactions and it's cheap. The SDK is available here: https://github.com/orao-network/solana-vrf and it's anchor compatible. Check the CPI and off-chain implementation examples here: https://github.com/orao-network/solana-vrf/tree/master/rust/examples

Answer (score 2):

Switchboard offers a VRF on solana: https://docs.switchboard.xyz/randomness

Answer (score 1):

While waiting for chainlink VRF you can also have a hasher and feed it with enough entropy to have a simulacre of random.
But the repartition will be off for sure.

I do that with caller pubkey, current time from `clock`, and price of BTC at call time from chainlink oracle. But that's temporary, waiting on chainlink VRF.

Comment: Is Chainlink VRF going to be accessible from Solana any time soon?